# Dividing map into features with invisible divisor lines using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features, vector-grid

I'm working with QGIS 1.8.0. Is there a way to divide a map with a grid but make the divisor lines invisible? I have a shapefile as the one in the left and I want it to see as the one in the right but still having the divisions (with the 82 different features).

[image: actual images]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the polygon border to 'No Pen' in style section of the layer Properties dialog box.